# Eclipse: change default HTML comment from <!-- --> to <!--/* */-->?

Tags: eclipse, aem, htl

I'm working on an Adobe AEM project in Eclipse. I'd like `Ctrl+Shift C` to generate comments in the preferred format for AEM, i.e. `<!--/* comment */-->`. Where can that be changed?

Comment: I guess you should create a new custom keyboard binding with Eclipse Rcp plugin. As it is not specifically for sightly it will be a Html editor you will be using for sightly html extension files

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> after selecting the lines you want to comment for multiple line comment.